# Create System Wide Touch Bar Item

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstouchbar

I would like to create a custom touch bar item that is available system wide on OS X on the 2016 MacBook pros.

Is it possible to add touch bar items at the system level at this point?  If so, where is the documentation for this?

Comment: I suspect it's still private API at this point.  Maybe we'll hear something at WWDC17?